# Add styles to React.Fragment

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Im working with React and my components follows this files structure schema:

```
- componentName
  |- componentName.tsx
  |- componentName.scss
```

There are some of these components that are wrap with a `<React.Fragment>` like that:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Is there a way to select this element in `css` ? Something like:

```css
React.Fragment {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Because it's not possible to add an `id` or a `className` to it. Any idea ?

Comment: *Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM.* So, there is no element in DOM, nothing to style. https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: Fragment doesn't appear in the DOM. It's basically an escape hatch that allows you to return an array of components from a component, so no you can't style it because it technically doesnt exist.

Comment: The point of a fragment is that it won't render anything. So no you would not be able to select it like that. If you need to do something like this why not just use a `div`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have pointed out in comments, `React.Fragment` does not add any extra nodes to the DOM. But in your case, it seems like you need to add a parent node. You can either add padding to `ChildA` or replace `React.Fragment` with a `div`. With the latter, I'd be mindful of any styling that expects 3 elements (with `React.Fragment`) and instead receives one element (`div`).